# How to add multiple conditions on a single field in views?

Tags: 7, views

I have two fields in my content type. `State` and `test` . `State` have two values `active` and `inactive` and `test` is a `boolean` field.

I want to display the content of this content type using views which will display:

```
active content
inactive content if test is FALSE
```

How can I do this in views?

I tried with views filter groups and it generates this condition.

```
WHERE ((( (node.status = '1') AND (node.type IN  ('mycontnt')) AND (state = 'active') )OR( (state = '4') AND (test = '0') )))
```

But this is not displaying the correct content as I want.

Answer (score 0):

So far as there is no support for nested groups in Drupal 7, we shoud do it slight differently.

Join general filters (Published and Node type) in first `AND` group. May be we also should to add there "State IS NOT NULL" condition to exclude content with empty State field.

In second group we should place State = 'active' OR test = 'false'. This group - `OR` group.  In the Views admin interface in would be somthing like this:

[image]